# Entity Getters hitting the database

Tags: oracle, hibernate, entity, getter-setter

I have an entity called USER which has been annotated as @entity and @table.. Which a table in oracle db

```
@Entity
@Table(name=“USER”)
Public User {
    @Id
    @column(name=“ID”)
    private Integer Id;
    @column(name=“ADDRESS”)
    private String Address;
    @column(name=“CONTACT”)
    private String contact;

//getters and setters

}
```

Now when I am fetching the data from db , I am doing something  like this which hits my Dao and its implementation to get the data from db.

```
User user = IUserDao.getById(table_id);
```

Post this, when I perform 
    user.getaddress() 
or 
    user.getContact 
which are getters over the entity table,It fires up a query back to the USER table and not the object which has already been got..

May be I’m missing something here..
Could someone help me out …..

Comment: have a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm